# Using dynamic property in connection pooling service for ExecuteSQL processor

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-nifi, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using ExecuteSQL to get the table from one or more database but i want to provide URL, Username, and password dynamically to the dbcpconnectionPool service so that i won't need more than one ExecuteSQL processor to retrieve data from different DB. It is found that controller service doesn't accept attribute from incoming flow file. So how to achieve it if it is possible. Someone pointed out that it can be achieved only by using rest api, if that is the case please provide a working example along with screenshots. It will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-nifi%5D+api a lot of questions how to change nifi flow on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation till NiFi 1.6.0. [NIFI-5121](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5121) and [NIFI-5229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5229) addressed this. The upcoming Apache NiFi 1.7.0 which would hopefully see a release in the next couple of days comes with this feature included.

Comment: so you mean there is not any possible way in nifi 1.6.0 to achieve it?

Comment: I'm saying I'm not aware of any way of doing it in 1.6.0 but lets see if someone has better suggestion

Comment: There isn't a way to do it until 1.7.0 is released, and just to be clear, even with 1.7.0 you still need to defined all of the DBCPConnectionPools ahead of time, but then you can have one ExecuteSQL processor that dynamically selects which one to use.