# Execute single query on multiple shemas - NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using execute sql to execute a query on MySql. Right now I need to specify the schema name where ever I use table name.

Is there any way I can configure the schema name and run the query on any desired schema name I choose to?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **NiFi-1.7** then you can dynamically select DBCP connection pools.

Refer to [NiFi-5229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5229) Jira addressing this improvement.

If you are following this way you need to `define connection pools` before using them and then using one **ExecuteSQL** processor we are going to select the connection pools [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961167/using-dynamic-property-in-connection-pooling-service-for-executesql-processor) based on the attribute.

If you are using previous versions of `NiFi-1.7` then unfortunately we need to **specify schema name for each query**.